# Angular 9 ngx-bootstrap date range picker selection display two input box like check-in and check-out date

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

How can we display selected start and end date in two different input boxes like check-in and check-out date using angular ngx-bootstrap range date picker calendar?

I am using the angular 9 with ngx-bootstrap date range calendar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, that such kind of functionality exists right now.
You can create a github issue in the repo, perhaps, somebody already made some workaround, which will be good for you